How to mock a remote module (remote React component) in jest?
I have a React component for which I'm writing test cases using Jest and React Testing library.
MyComponent.tsx:
import RemoteComponent from '@remote-module/remote-component'

function MyComponent = ({triggerLog}) => {
  const errorHandler = (error) => {
    triggerLog(error)
  }
 
  return (
      <RemoteComponent
        errorLogCallback={errorHandler}
      />
  )
}

export default MyComponent

Please tell me how do I mock RemoteComponent as I want to cover the errorHandler method in Jest.

You can mock it like this
// this is needed as jest hoists the `.mock` calls on top
// and also variables prefixed with `mock`
const mockUseEffect = useEffect;

jest.mock(
  '@remote-module/remote-component',
  () =>
    ({ errorLogCallback }: { errorLogCallback: (error: Error) => void }) => {
      mockUseEffect(() => {
        errorLogCallback(new Error('testing error'));
      });
      return null;
    },
);

you can expect the triggerLog to have been called once the component is rendered
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should pass the error wrapping it in useless function', () => {
    const triggerLog = jest.fn();
    render(<MyComponent triggerLog={triggerLog} />);

    expect(triggerLog).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error('testing error'));
  });
});

